# Ember {{#link-to}} doesn't transition to route

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

This is my current situation. I have a campaign view route which is nested within a campaigns route. I'm using dynamic segments so the view page only displays the necessary details for that particular campaign.

This is illustrated in my routes:

```
TM.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("campaigns", function(){
        this.route("view", { path: "/view/:id" }),
        this.route("create"),
        this.route("edit", { path: "/edit/:id" })
    })
});
```

The URL for the view page is:

```
/campaigns/view/2
```

The campaigns route has an edit link (which only appears in the view page) that should take the user to the edit page with form which is pre-populated with the details from the current item.

So I have linked the model to the edit page as such:

```
TM.CampaignsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find("campaign", params.id);
    }
});
```

and the edit link within the campaigns route is:

```
  <li>{{#link-to "campaigns.edit"}}Edit Campaign Code Info{{/link-to}}</li>
```

The link changes from:

```
/campaigns/view/2
```

to

```
/campaigns/edit/2
```

..but for some reason, the edit template doesn't appear/load on the page, neither is a GET request made to the model and I'm not sure why.

If I refresh the page, the form appears but nothing happens on the initial click.

**Update**

When I hard code the ID into the {{#link-to}},

```
  <li>{{#link-to "campaigns.edit" "2"}}Edit Campaign Code Info{{/link-to}}</li>
```

the link works how it should but I when I use campaign.id, I get

```
This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.
```

**Update  2**

So the problem is that the link which edits the campaign is in the top level route (campaigns) while the data I want to edit is in campaigns view. The link within campaigns doesn't know what the ID of the data in campaigns view is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I have more info about your issue - I decided to post another answer. The issue is that you have a color model which keeps on changing that you need to keep track of at the parent level.

Based on the Ember.js' documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/), I came up with the following solution:

```
App.ColorManagerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentColour: null
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['colorManager'],
  currentColour:Ember.computed.alias('controllers.colorManager.currentColour'),

  editMode: false,

  actions: {
    goToDetails: function(colour){
      this.set("editMode",true);
      return this.transitionToRoute("index.view", colour);
  }
 }
});

App.IndexViewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['colorManager'],

  currentColour:Ember.computed.alias('controllers.colorManager.currentColour'),

  modelChanged: function(){
    this.set('currentColour', this.get('model'));
  }.observes('model')

});
```

Basically, the `currentColour` property (although spelled incorrectly ;)) gets synched up across the parent and child controllers.

Then, in your `index` (parent) template, you just need to say

```
  {{#if editMode}}
    {{#link-to "index.edit" currentColour}}Edit Colour{{/link-to}}
  {{/if}}
```

Working solution on jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/newijesifa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

`<li>{{#link-to "campaigns.edit" campaign}}Edit Campaign Code Info{{/link-to}}</li>`

The following link explains this really well - http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/

Comment: The edit page doesn't appear and I get the warning: This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.

Comment: Right, you are missing `campaign` variable or whatever the variable should be you are linking to.

Comment: See the link I posted in the answer

Comment: If I hard code the value, it seems to work. How do I get the ID of the record? I only get the ID when using an each loop but that's not required.

Comment: `serialize` hook in the `Ember.Route` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize determines how the model you pass in relates to the stuff in `params`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but using serialize only works if I'm using an {{#each}} around the link but I'm not. The page I'm linking from is only displaying an object. I can't seem to get the ID of the object on display

Comment: serialize has nothing to do with #each

Comment: So the problem is that the link which edits the campaign is in the top level route (campaigns) while the data I want to edit is in campaigns view. The link within campaigns doesn't know what the ID of the data in campaigns view is.

Comment: You should have all the data you need. Can you post a jsbin? Go to emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Here is an emberjs.jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yakiga/5/. By the way, thanks for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: The easiest thing would be to move the Edit Colour link to index.view like this http://jsbin.com/giqotuparu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a change to your nested route/resource structure. Take a look at this Ember page under the Nested Routes section for an example:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

I would make my router something like:

```
TM.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("campaigns", function(){
        this.route("create");
        this.resource("campaign", { path: "/:id", function(){
            this.route("view");
            this.route("edit");
        });
    })
});
```

your link-to helper should now implicitly be working with the id param in the url so the link-to should work without having to pass values to it:

```
<li>{{#link-to "campaigns.edit"}}Edit Campaign Code Info{{/link-to}}</li>
```